# Parse html with jsoup and remove the tag block

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to remove everything between a tag. An example input may be

Input:

```
<body>
  start
  <div>
    delete from below
    <div class="XYZ">
      first div having this class
      <div>
        waste
      </div>
      <div class="XYZ">
        second div having this class
      </div>
      waste
    </div>
    delete till above
  </div>
  <div>
    this will also remain
  </div>
  end
</body>
```

The output will be:

```
<body>
  start
  <div>
    delete from below
    delete till above
  </div>
  <div>
    this will also remain
  </div>
  end
</body>
```

Basically, I have to remove the entire block for the first occurrence of `<div class="XYZ">`

Thanks,

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I found the answer in the Jsoup selector.

Solution will be something like:

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    doc.select("div.XYZ").first().remove();
    return doc.body().outerHtml();


But here is one problem, when I ran this, it gave me correct answer for the html string that has `<div class="XYZ">` but it will return `java.lang.NullPointerException` if `<div class="XYZ">` is not present in the input html string.

Do I need to check everything and do the step only if I find the div of that type?

Thanks.

Comment: I cannot answer my own question??? awwww

Comment: No you can't. but you can post your solution as an *answer* an then accept it (see: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). if your question is solved, please to it that way.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You better iterate over *all* elements found. so you can be shure that

- a.) all elements are removed and
- b.) there's nothing done if there's no element.

**Example:**

```
Document doc = ...

for( Element element : doc.select("div.XYZ") )
{
    element.remove();
}
```

---

**Edit:**

*( An addition to my comment )*

Don't use exception handling when a simple *null- / range check* is enough here:

```
doc.select("div.XYZ").first().remove();
```

instead:

```
Elements divs = doc.select("div.XYZ");

if( !divs.isEmpty() )
{
    /*
     * Here it's safe to call 'first()' since there at least one element.
     */
}
```

Comment: Thanks ollo... I did it with doc.select("div.XYZ").first.remove(); and kept this in a try block, if an exception is caught (that means required field is absent), it will return the original string. That way it was solved. But yours is a better way of doing this.

Comment: *Don't* use exceptionhandling for this - a simple *null check* is much better.

Comment: Thanks once again @ollo.... Your solution gave me solution for another problem. where I have to check the html tag for a particular owntext and remove it.  I did not know that you can remove element while iterating it in for-each loop, and this is coming to be handy . Thanks.....

Comment: Please see my edit. btw. you're right; using a loop is better since the loop is skipped if there are no elements (`first()` throws a `NullPointerException` instead).

Comment: It's possible to use a selector which selects only those elements with have a owntext (or have none).

Comment: can you have two attr for an element. Like I have to match <blockquote cite="mid:5159BE77.1020209@xyz.com" type="cite">... For this I am doing doc.select("blockquote[cite~="+regex+"]"); where regex = "\".*?\""        But this is not happening

Comment: got the solution, you can AND the attributes condition using [][]... Though comma is used for OR

Comment: So if your question is solved, feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
String data = null;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("e://XMLFile.xml"));
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    while ((data = br.readLine()) != null) {
        builder.append(data);
    }
    System.out.println(builder);
    String replaceAll = builder.toString().replaceAll("<div class=\"XYZ\".+?</div>", "");
    System.out.println(replaceAll);
```

I have read the input XML from a file and stored it in a StringBuilder object by reading it line by line, and then replaced the entire  tag will empty string.

Comment: You can easily use Jsoup for that. in general its a better idea not to use regex but a html library (like jsoup)

Comment: @ollo : thanks for the information. I did not know about Jsoup.

Comment: @ Ankur. Thanks, But I gave the solution using jsoup in the comment.   Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html); doc.select("div.XYZ").first().remove(); return doc.body().outerHtml();

Answer (score 1):

This may help you.

```
 String selectTags="div,li,p,ul,ol,span,table,tr,td,address,em";
 /*selecting some specific tags */
 Elements webContentElements = parsedDoc.select(selectTags); 
 String removeTags = "img,a,form"; 
 /*Removing some tags from selected elements*/
 webContentElements.select(removeTags).remove();
```

Comment: Is there any difference between this and the accepted answer? The corner case OP mentioned also seems to be covered.

Answer (score 0):

I asked this problem yesterday and thanks to ollo's answer. It was solved.
There is en extension of the above problem. I did not know if I have to start a new post or chain this one. So, in this confusion I am chaining it here.. Admins pls, pardon me if I had to make a separate post for this.

In the above problem, I have to remove a tag block with matching component.

The real scenario is:
It should remove the tag block with matching component + remove `<br />` surrounding it.

Referring to the above example.

```
<body>
  start
  <div>
    delete from below
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="XYZ">
      first div having this class
      <div>
        waste
      </div>
      <div class="XYZ">
        second div having this class
      </div>
      waste
    </div>
    <br />
    delete till above
  </div>
  <div>
    this will also remain
  </div>
  end
</body>
```

should also give the same output:

```
<body>
  start
  <div>
    delete from below
    delete till above
  </div>
  <div>
    this will also remain
  </div>
  end
</body>
```

Because it has `<br />` above and below the html tag block to remove....

Just to re-iterate, I am using the solution given by ollo to match and remove the tag block.

```
for( Element element : doc.select("div.XYZ") )
{
    element.remove();
}
```

Thanks,
Shekhar