# JSoup Remove Elements

Tags: java, jsoup

Even though, this may sound too basic, I would like to ask how do I remove an element from doc using Jsoup.

I tried searching for it, but no success.

Here is problem:

```
Elements myNewElements = doc.getElementsByAttribute("hello");

//Now I need to perform some other methods on myNewElements before removing.
//Hence..suggested method says,
doc.getElementsByAttribute("hello").remove();
```

This works fine. But I believe selecting same elements again and again could prove memory hungry. Is it possible ?

```
doc.select(myNewElements).remove();
```

//Try to select myNewElements from doc.

Comment: The `select()` method doesn't take `Elements` as argument - it takes **strings**! http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: yeah, I have mentioned in question.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you didn't add any new elements that match your inital select, you don't need to select the elements again.

Each element in elements has a reference to its parent and the remove() method just tells the parent to remove that child element.

In essence, just doing:

```
myNewElements.remove()
```

should work.

Comment: Posting those exceptions would be helpful. Even if it's working, exceptions are a good hint that there's something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Better loop over the elements and remove them within:

```
for( Element element : doc.select(myNewElements) )
{
    element.remove();
}
```

There's a similar question: [Parse html with jsoup and remove the tag block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795796/parse-html-with-jsoup-and-remove-the-tag-block/15796073)

Comment: how if myNewElements.get(0).remove() ? can it be?

Comment: This is not needed and adds extra processing. Removing the root element that you want removed also removes all child elements.