# How to remove a specific tag from html using Java?

Tags: java, html, regex

I have a large html. I want to remove a specific span tag which can be straightforward as.

```
<span class=GramE> blah blah blah</span>
Output: bla bla bla
```

OR

```
<span class=a><span class=GramE>bla bla bla</span></span>
Output: <span class=a>bla bla bla</span>
```

Or in any other intermingled format. However, it should preserve the text between  ...

Actual html

```
<td width=265 colspan=3 valign=top style='width:7.0cm;background:white;
 padding:0cm 5.75pt 0cm 5.75pt'> <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;text-align:justify;line-height:normal'><span class=GramE><span style='font-size:13.0pt'>(Here</span></span><span style='font-size:13.0pt'> Lorem ispsum. Lorem ispsum. Lorem ispsum. Lorem ispsum )</span></p>
            </td>
```

I have tried the following code however, the replaceAll() doesnt seem to work. There are many intermingled span-tags in my html text which need this output. Please help me figure out where am I going wrong.

```
String filename = "file-location.html";
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {

        String line;
        String sb = "";

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            String tmp = line.replaceAll("<span class=GramE[^>]*>/g", "");
            System.out.print(tmp);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: The ``/g`` at the end of your regex looks wrong. Remove it and try again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @f1sh It doesnt work even if I remove /g. I tried the same before this

Comment: Please use an HTML parser (e.g. JSoup) and edit your file appropriatly.

Comment: Try [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/). It handles html perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) (thanks to @Maurice Perry's comment)

I recommend you to use `jsoup`, as showed here: [Parse html with jsoup and remove the tag block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15796073/5734097)

Comment: Good idea. I will try it ASAP. Hope it works. However, I was thinking of easy work using Regex

Answer (score 1):

This answer was done before *actual html* is added to the question.
JSoup address grammatical issues, when RegEx may address lexical issues. So, for this problem, using JSoup is the only way.

However, this answer may help RegEx users:

```
line.replaceAll("<span class=GramE>([^<]*)</span>", "$1" );
```

`([^<]*)` is a capturing group and `$1` is its value.

see the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String)).

Test case:

```
public class RemoveTagFromPage {

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      final String text =
         "<html><body>" +
            "<p>hello</p>" +
            "<span class=a>" +
               "<span class=GramE>bla bla bla</span>" +
            "</span>" +
         "</body></html>";
      System.out.println(
         text.replaceAll("<span class=GramE>([^<]*)</span>", "$1" ));
   }
}
```

Execution log:

```
<html><body><p>hello</p><span class=a>bla bla bla</span></body></html>
```

Comment: Its a precise test-case. However, in case of inter-looped span tags. It fails.

Comment: Revise the specification, please.

Comment: I have revised my question.

Comment: Tested, passed. Post a real test case please. The sample you post is missing quote.

Comment: Added a part of real test case.

Comment: With this updated spec, the problem isn't lexical but grammatical, so JSoup is the best tool.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I will do it using Jsoup